# Nodemon stuck on "[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart" when I run nodemon .\index.js

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, discord, discord.js, nodemon

Making a bot with discord.js and I'm following a tutorial, when I run "nodemon .\index.js"  in the VSC terminal, it  returns back with

```
[nodemon] 2.0.9
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node .\index.js`
[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart
```

My code:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const Bot = new Discord.Client({intents: [Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS, Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS]})

Bot.on('ready',() => {
    console.log("The bot is online")
})

Bot.login("Bot Token Here")
```

I've looked through posts of this same exact problem but I can't seem to find a answer to my problem, and on the tutorial nobody else seems to have this problem. I've restarted this bot project 2 times and I carefully followed the tutorial making sure I typed and installed everything correctly, but it still comes back with "[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart"

Comment: No, you don't have to do that @J.Titus in discord.js

Comment: Can you please add a top-level console log to confirm the code is executed? and try running it with `node index.js` aswell

Comment: @Apachedev dev How do I get the top level console log? I'm new to VSC so I don't know much. node index.js ran nothing either

Comment: You just add a console.log anywhere but not inside any {} like for example below the `const Bot = new....` line

Comment: @ArnavMishra I updated nodemon and reran the project with nodemon .\index.js, and it worked. the log said "the bot is now online" so i guess updating worked

Comment: Yep! its fixed now